# function call missing argument list error

Tags: c++, irrlicht, bulletphysics

am trying to convert a [bullet](http://www.bulletphysics.com) quaternion(btQuaternion) to an [irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net) quaternion(irr::core::quaternion) for a game am prototyping.

```
        btQuaternion orientation= rigidBody->getOrientation();//now turn bullet quaternion -> irrlicht
        finalOrientation= core::quaternion(orientation.getX, orientation.getY, orientation.getZ, orientation.getW);
```

However am getting an error i cant figure out.

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'btQuadWord::getX': function call missing argument list; use '&btQuadWord::getX' to create a pointer to member c:\users\matia\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bulletimplant\bulletimplant\bulletimplant.cpp  86
Error   2   error C3867: 'btQuadWord::getY': function call missing argument list; use '&btQuadWord::getY' to create a pointer to member c:\users\matia\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bulletimplant\bulletimplant\bulletimplant.cpp  86
Error   3   error C3867: 'btQuadWord::getZ': function call missing argument list; use '&btQuadWord::getZ' to create a pointer to member c:\users\matia\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bulletimplant\bulletimplant\bulletimplant.cpp  86
Error   4   error C3867: 'btQuaternion::getW': function call missing argument list; use '&btQuaternion::getW' to create a pointer to member c:\users\matia\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\bulletimplant\bulletimplant\bulletimplant.cpp  86
```

visual studio is complaining about a function call missing an argument list but i cant find a solution. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming none of the functions expect any argument, I believe you need :

```
finalOrientation= core::quaternion(orientation.getX(), orientation.getY(), orientation.getZ(), orientation.getW());
```

The compiler complains because `getX`, `getY`, `getZ` and `getW` are functions, and functions should be followed by an argument list when invoked.

Comment: What if you are passing OpenGL's callback functions?